Iterating bootstrap cards with Jinja
I am trying to iterate cards inside of card groups from Bootstrap using Jinja, so there are no more than 4 cards inside of 1 group, but I finish with 1 card side to side. This is my code:
{% set n = 0 %}
{% for vid in videos %}
    {% if n % 4 == 0 %}
        {% if n % 4 == 0 %}
            </div> <!-- Close previous card-group -->
        {% endif %}
        <div class="card-group"> <!-- Start a new card-group -->
    {% endif %}
    <div class="card">
    <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
    {% set n = n + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
</div>

I tried changing different div's places, but it didn't do a lot

The problem with card groups is that a group must contain exactly as many cards as all the others, because if the number is lower, the cards in the group will scale. However, your list of videos can vary in number and does not always contain a number that is divisible by 4.
I recommend using grid cards. In this case, they are all the same size and unused space remains free.
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
    {% for vid in vids -%}
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card h-100">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title {{ loop.index }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-body-secondary">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor -%}
</div>

